# How to notify users of new app version in build phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

Hello please I need help, I am developing a HTML5 and jquery mobile app and compiling using build phonegap.

I intend to host the app on my server, now my problem is how do I notify users of a new version of the app and at the same time allow them to update to the new version (as it is done in app store).

I have googled this for two days now and can't seem to be making any head way. Are there plugins I can use?

Suggestions will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with apple developers guides to develop my web app and maybe this can help you if you are working with apples "rules"/ developing for apple users:

https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

There is a guido on how you can make local notifications or push notifications. Also includes all the code you will need.

Hope it helps!

Edit: sorry just noticed that you are working for Android users. Maybe if you look on Android API or their developer program you will find something. :')